# How to fix this Error in EV3 Classroom?

Tags: ev3, repair

So I got the error "Heads up! Couldn't open this project" and did research and found out that it is a generic error, then looked up the exact error on this site: https://legoapptools.azurewebsites.net it showed me this error:

```
#WARNLONESTK1 Lonely stack ev3move_rotation-wheel()
#WARNLONESTK1 Lonely stack procedures_call()
#WARNLONESTK1 Lonely stack ev3sound_playSoundUntilDone()
```

I understand that the problem is that I have Blocks floating in my project, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is a link to the project file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/aqsg90fv7mptqmi1o5zhc/WRO2024-1.lmsp?rlkey=nd6j1b8dlcrt45iadyqy5ri2d&dl=0

Comment: The Lonely stack is not an error. This particular file contains a null value in a list which isn't valid. I updated my answer at https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/16945/3498 to describe how to fix this.

Comment: Here is a link to the repaired file [WRO2024 1 - fixed.lmsp](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApX9UuctkzDD9V9xz67m2HPGcgnQ?e=wYeTkm).

Comment: @DavidLechner thank you very much I saw you're answer to the other post but I couldn’t solve it on my own. You are a life saver! I hope they will add an easier solution to this. Greetings Jonathan